# How to use Python 3.5 syntax in readthedocs combined with autodoc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc, read-the-docs

I would like to generate documentation (including automatically generated documentation with autodoc) for my project using [readthedocs.org](http://readthedocs.org). However, my project uses Python 3.5 syntax (`async` and `await`) and it doesn't look like it can handle that. The build succeeds, although I get a lot of errors like this:

```
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sparrow/checkouts/latest/docs/source/entity.rst:176: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'sparrow.entity'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sparrow/envs/latest/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sparrow/checkouts/latest/sparrow/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .model import *
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/sparrow/checkouts/latest/sparrow/model.py", line 37
    async def install(self):
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You may want to ask for help from `readthedocs.org`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/support.html: "If you have questions about how to use Read the Docs, or have an issue that isn’t related to a bug, Stack Overflow is the best place to ask. " :)

Comment: So you're saying that Stack Overflow is the wrong place then? https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dietrich's answer (my bad for not finding the github issue), I found a very valuable hint about **conda**. It appears to be somewhat like virtualenv, but it has the power to install binaries and python versions themselves.

I was able to get it working by adding two files to my github repo, both in the root (although environment.yml could go somewhere else). If anyone wants to get a basic conda environment going, you can use this instead of having to install conda yourself.

**readthedocs.yml**

```
conda:
    file: environment.yml
```

**environment.yml**

```
name: py35
dependencies:
- openssl=1.0.2g=0
- pip=8.1.1=py35_0
- python=3.5.1=0
- readline=6.2=2
- setuptools=20.3=py35_0
- sqlite=3.9.2=0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- xz=5.0.5=1
- zlib=1.2.8=0
- pip:
  - momoko>=2.2.3
  - psycopg2>=2.6.1
  - tornado==4.3
```

Normally you can add requirements in a requirements.txt file that are then installed through pip. When using conda you have to list them in the environment.yml file, like I already did with momoko, psycopg2 and tornado.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are a bit outdated as nowadays Readthedocs.org does support Python 3.5 and 3.6. To use it one has to configure the `readthedocs.yml`. Documentation about this can be found here: http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml-config.html.

A minimum example that would make Readthedocs.org use Python 3.5 is:

```
build:
    image: latest

python:
    version: 3.5
```

If you have any dependencies, this can be handled via a `requirements.txt` file or via `setup.py`. For example if you want to use the `setup.py` you simply tell Readthedocs.org to install your package:

```
build:
    image: latest

python:
    version: 3.5
    setup_py_install: true
```

Comment: Just as a note: as of today this feature is still in beta state but seems to work fine. The file's name can be prefixed with a dot: `.readthedocs.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

Readthedocs.org does not currently support Python 3.5, see [issue 1990: python 3.5 support for build system](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1990).

Comment: Oh well, seems I missed that issue. Googling for anything related to 'readthedocs' gives a lot of documentation you're not looking for :)